# iOS 7 sizeWithAttributes: replacement for sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize

Tags: objective-c, ios7

How do you return a multiline text CGSize from the new iOS 7 method sizeWithAttributes?

I would like this to produce the same results as sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize.

```
NSString *text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu urna quis lacus imperdiet scelerisque a nec neque. Mauris eget feugiat augue, vitae porttitor mi. Curabitur vitae sollicitudin augue. Donec id sapien eros. Proin consequat tellus in vehicula sagittis. Morbi sed felis a nibh hendrerit hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit."

CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16.0] }];
```

This method only produces the height for a single line of text.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673176/sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-deprecated/19137272?noredirect=1#19137272

Comment: +1 for having the same font as me :)

Answer (score 297, accepted):

well you can try this :

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]};
// NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
// available only on ios7.0 sdk.
CGRect rect = [textToMeasure boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attributes
                                          context:nil];
```

Comment: For the first time i see this notation for dictionaries `@{...}`. What is it called?

Comment: Any way to specify max number of lines?

Comment: Bro, i was almost losing my faith in SO, then i came here.

Comment: Wow.  So much more obtuse than the original `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` method that was deprecated.  Apple must really hate us.  In any case, +1.

Comment: Why do you use `MAXFLOAT` instead of `CGFLOAT_MAX`?

Comment: Actually I wrote this code quickly to answer the question.. Thanks for pointing this out the correct constant to use is CGFLOAT_MAX, edited the answer

Comment: Swift version:
```var size = textToMeasure.boundingRectWithSize(
                CGSizeMake(width, CGFloat.max),
                options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                attributes:attrs,
                context:nil).size```

Comment: its not working with New Line Character my string is like @"Hello this is new \n Label testing"

Comment: @iOSRocks have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602491/boundingrectwithsize-does-not-respect-word-wrapping

Comment: If getting a 'extra argument attributes' error in Swift version make sure that the boundingRectWithSize is performed on self.textLabel.attributedText.string rather than self.textLabel.attributedText - I just spent ages trying to get my head round that oversight

Comment: This is always returning the size for a string, regardless of the font size I give it. Why could that be happening? (I'm on OS X, not iOS)

Comment: where does width come from, is it a value already calculated or do i need to have another `CGFloat width = 0.0;` outside of this function since i will be using the width later from the struct, hence my minor confusion.  thank you!

Answer (score 23):

This is how I did it:

```
    // Get a font to draw it in
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 28];

CGRect textRect;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

// How big is this string when drawn in this font?
textRect.size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

// Draw the string
[text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: This won't work if a long string should break at end of line. Refer to elio.d's answer, which is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my method to deal with both situations, goes in an `NSString` category.

```
- (CGSize) sizeWithFontOrAttributes:(UIFont *) font {
    if (IS_IOS7) {
        NSDictionary *fontWithAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
        return [self sizeWithAttributes:fontWithAttributes];
    } else {
        return [self sizeWithFont:font];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Xamarin.iOS:

```
UIFont descriptionLabelFont =  UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (11);
NSString textToMeasure = (NSString)DescriptionLabel.Text;

CGRect labelRect = textToMeasure.GetBoundingRect (
    new CGSize(this.Frame.Width, nfloat.MaxValue), 
    NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, 
    new UIStringAttributes () { Font = descriptionLabelFont }, 
    new NSStringDrawingContext ()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.3:**

```swift
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14)]
let rect = NSString(string: textToMeasure).boundingRectWithSize(
        CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), 
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, 
        attributes: attributes, context: nil)
```

**Swift 4:**

```swift
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14)]
let rect = NSString(string: textToMeasure).boundingRect(
                    with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                    attributes: attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], context: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the text, font, numberOfLines and width of your label set, this method returns the size of your label:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

CGSize size = [myLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];`
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you're looking at `UITextView`, you can always use the `NSLayoutManager` method:

```
CGSize textSize = [textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer].size;
```

You can also find the line height for a given font by:

```
UIFont *font;
CGFloat lineHeight = font.lineHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

[As a new user, I cannot post a comment to @testing's answer, but to make his answer (for xamarin.ios) more useful]

We can return a CGRect and only use the height parameter for the gui item we are targeting UIButton etc.Passing in any parameters we need as below

```
    public CGRect GetRectForString(String strMeasure, int fontSize, nfloat guiItemWidth)
    {
        UIFont descriptionLabelFont =  UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (fontSize);
        NSString textToMeasure = (NSString)strMeasure;

        CGRect labelRect = textToMeasure.GetBoundingRect (
            new CGSize(guiItemWidth, nfloat.MaxValue), 
            NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, 
            new UIStringAttributes () { Font = descriptionLabelFont }, 
            new NSStringDrawingContext ()
        );

        return labelRect;
    }
```

---

```
        header_Revision.Frame = new CGRect (5
                                            , verticalAdjust
                                            , View.Frame.Width-10
                                            , GetRectForString( header_Revision.Title(UIControlState.Normal)
                                                              , 18
                                                              , View.Frame.Width-10 ).Height
                                            );
```

Comment: This was actually supposed to be under testing's nice code for Xamarin.IOS :) Hope it helps anyone :)

Comment: When you have more rep, a comment like this would typically be appended to the post.  You cant do that yet, so thanks for additional data, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize stringsize = [lbl.text sizeWithAttributes:
                         @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:FontProximaNovaRegular size:12.0]}];


CGSize adjustedSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(stringsize.width), ceilf(stringsize.height));
```

use `ceilf` method to manage properlly