# boundingRectWithSize does not respect word wrapping

Tags: ios, uitextview, frame

I create a UITextView, add text to it, and put it in the view (with a container)

```
UITextView *lyricView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:screen];
lyricView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%@\n\n\n\n\n\n", lyrics];
[container addSubview:lyricView];
[self.view addSubview:container];
```

I then get the size of it for use with a button and add it to the UITextView

```
CGRect size = [lyrics boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(lyricView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[lyricView font]}
                                 context:nil];
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[doneButton setFrame:CGRectMake(56, size.size.height + 55, 208, 44)];
[doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[lyricView addSubview:doneButton];
```

This works in *most cases*. This will respect \n line breaks (like I added in my stringWithFormat) but it will not respect word wraps automatically added by the text view. So if `lyrics` has a line that doesn't fit on the screen, the UITextView will wrap it (as it's supposed to), but `size` is now slightly shorter than it should be because it did not respect the text view wrap.

Comment: have you tried replace `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin `by `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading`?which **Uses the font leading for calculating line heights**

Comment: @johnMa When I use `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading`, it returns 0. When I use `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` or both, I have the issue described above.

Comment: Any update on this?  I am having the same problem and can't seem to find a good answer.

Comment: @BarlowTucker Unfortunately, no. Please let me know if you find one!

Comment: @BarlowTucker I found a solution! Check below for the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did some more research and ended up finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative).

```
CGSize textSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
CGFloat textHeight = textSize.height;
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: This works perfectly and it's so much simpler than all the other solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can tell `boundingRectWithSize` to process the string in word-wrapping mode. You have to add an `NSParagraphStyle` attribute to the attributes parameter, with its `lineBreakMode` set to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`. So:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];     
// ...whatever other attributes you need...
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paraStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[attr setObject:paraStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```

then use `attr` as the attributes argument to `boundingRectWithSize`.

You can easily extend/generalise this technique to read other attributes including existing paragraph style attributes from whatever source makes sense.

Comment: In fact this doesn't work for me too! In some cases a single word is broken into two parts and placed in two lines...

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem, where boundingRectWithSize is measuring the text after wrapping the lines, and I want the unwrapped size. So I set the paragraph style to NSLineBreakByClipping and now I'm getting the results I wanted.

Comment: This solved the issue where width was smaller than it can be! Thx!

Answer (score 7):

Should use `(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)` for `options` parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't make any difference. Still getting incorrect values.