# How to convert sizeWithFont to sizeWithAttributes(iOS 7)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsstring, cgsize

How to get `CGSize` value for a `NSString` in iOS 7 SDK, just want convert the below lines of code with `sizeWithAttributes`.

```
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 sizeWithAttributes: replacement for sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145078/ios-7-sizewithattributes-replacement-for-sizewithfontconstrainedtosize)

Answer (score 10):

you can try this...

```
 NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]};

[text sizeWithAttributes:attributes]
```

or

```
CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
```