# sizeWithAttributes() not giving me the right height after several break lines

Tags: ios, nsstring, core-graphics

Im using `sizeWithAttributes()` to get the size of a string with `\n`'s in it. It works up to a number of 5 `\n`'s and then it starts to return half a line too low on the height, so the last row gets cut in half (---).

Are there any other attributes than Font which will help me in my situation?

Code:

```
str = "text\ntext\ntext\ntext\ntext" 
label = CATextLayer()
label. ...
```

---

```
let textSize = str.uppercaseString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: label.font as String, size: label.fontSize)!])
```

Comment: can please you post the code your having issues with?

Comment: @JoshuaSmith code added

Comment: please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145078/ios-7-sizewithattributes-replacement-for-sizewithfontconstrainedtosize/35812617#35812617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `label.font` might be not a string:

> The font to use, currently may be either a CTFontRef, a CGFontRef, or a string naming the font

So you'd better perform some checks if you're not setting it in your code (I'll write my example in ObjC, but it should be pretty simple to translate it to Swift):

```
NSString* fontName;

CFTypeRef font = label.font;
if (CFGetTypeID(font) == CFStringGetTypeID())
{
    fontName = (__bridge NSString *)(font);
}
else if (CFGetTypeID(font) == CGFontGetTypeID())
{
    fontName = CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyFullName((CGFontRef)font));
}
else if (CFGetTypeID(font) == CTFontGetTypeID())
{
    fontName = CFBridgingRelease(CTFontCopyFullName((CTFontRef)font));
}
```

Second, CATextLayer (unlike UILabel or string drawing functions) seems to use line height multiple different from 1 when drawing string content, so you need to use paragraph style to measure it correctly:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.lineHeightMultiple = 1.05;

NSDictionary* attributes = @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:label.fontSize],
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
};

CGSize textSize = [str sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
```

Multiplier 1.05 was actually chosen after some experiments, and it works pretty good for different font sizes from 8 to 72.

Comment: It was the attribute that was needed, thank you! I knew it was some attribute I was missing for this purpose but didnt know which one. :)