# The exact size of a CGRect using CGSize ... sizeWithAttributes

Tags: objective-c, cgrect, cgsize

The code below is an example of how I use `CGRect` to draw some text when making a pdf document. I need to calculate the exact size of the `CGRect` being drawn with **comment1** so that the ones for **comment2**, **comment3** etc all start in the right place on the page.

The variable **currentLine** keeps track of where the end of the `CGRect` is on the page. It works fine for short comments but not long comments where subsequent comments overlap. The font and font size are correct.

```
textRect = CGRectMake(60, currentLine, 650, 300);
myString =  self.comments1.text;
[myString drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:_textAttributesNotBold ];

CGSize contentSize = [myString sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]}];
currentLine =  currentLine +  contentSize.height;
```

I wonder if the problem is with the `CGRectMake` using a 650 width. This does not seem to be taken into account in the `CGSize` .... `sizeWithAttributes`. What width does the `CGSize` .... `sizeWithAttributes` assume when calculating the **contentSize.height**?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you're doing this backward... why don't you calculate the content size first... then create a rect with that size... then draw the string in *that* rect?  And then... how come you're not passing the same arguments for `withAttributes:` to the method for calculating the size as you are to the method for actually drawing?

Comment: That makes sense but the problem is still the same. contentSize.height is calculated from sizeWithAttributes: but takes no account of the width of the CGRectMake. I don't understand how it calculates  the height without knowing the width of the frame.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 sizeWithAttributes: replacement for sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145078/ios-7-sizewithattributes-replacement-for-sizewithfontconstrainedtosize)

Comment: @nhgrif Helpful - thanks. I have seemed to come to a solution (added here) but seems a bit messy to me. Works though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a good way to do it but it seems to work:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]};
CGRect rect = [comment1.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(650, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];

CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(60, currentLine, 650, rect.size.height);
[comment1.text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes ];
currentLine =  currentLine +  rect.size.height;
```

Comment: You should use the `attributes` variable in both places that ask for text attributes.  And the last line could be simply: `currentLine += rect.size.height;`